# Embed a parameter into a activity object call

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using a json file for reading in config parameters.

```
{"process_delta":
            {
                "primary_keys": ["id"],
                "schema_name": "schema",
                "table_name": "table",
                "source_path":"folder/table/"
            }
}
```

Then in my pipeline with a lookup activity I can call the `source_path` in subgroub  `process_delta` with this:

`@activity('Lookup config details').output.firstRow.process_delta.source_path`

That works.

My issue is want to make my pipeline nice and generic to enable reuse and some existing pipelines don't have the same name for their sections. Is there a way to put a parameter into that formula so the subgroup can be different and still return the source_path value in it?

so like this:

`@activity('Lookup config details').output.firstRow.<something_resolved from_a_parameter_here>.source_path`

I've tried this but its not happy with it

`@activity('Lookup config details').output.firstRow.@{pipeline().parameters.p_config_section}.source_path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow[pipeline().parameters.param1].source_path
```

Here my `param1` value is `"process_delta"`.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thanks, that is strange how it doesn't need a period before the variable, I thought you'd missed it out but nope that's correct, it works